# Crashlytics sometimes stops working and throws error

Tags: android, crashlytics

I have integrated crashlytics in my android APP. sometimes it does not function properly and starts throwing error/exceptions and because of that my app crashes. stacktrace of error is as shown below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:192)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
       at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:204)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:144)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:215)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:192)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
       at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:204)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:144)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:215)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.TrimmedThrowableData.<init>(TrimmedThrowableData.java:19)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.TrimmedThrowableData.<init>(TrimmedThrowableData.java:20)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.TrimmedThrowableData.<init>(TrimmedThrowableData.java:20)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsController.java:1090)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeFatal(CrashlyticsController.java:852)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$400(CrashlyticsController.java:59)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(CrashlyticsController.java:292)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(CrashlyticsController.java:285)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:132)
       at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:431)
       at demand.inn.com.quflipfoodtruck.fragment.SettingsFragment$12.onNext(SettingsFragment.java:335)
       at demand.inn.com.quflipfoodtruck.fragment.SettingsFragment$12.onNext(SettingsFragment.java:319)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:215)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:132)
       at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:431)
       at demand.inn.com.quflipfoodtruck.fragment.SettingsFragment$12.onError(SettingsFragment.java:327)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
       at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:204)
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:144)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:215)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Do you use facebook Buck or freeline or okbuck?

Comment: Can you elaborate all the three options, that you have mentioned , because I am new to crashlytics, so I do not know them

Comment: All 3 of them are build systems for android. you probably don't use them

Comment: I have not integrated crashlytics via android plugin. I have integrated it manually

Comment: The crashlytics plugin is great. you should give it a try.

Comment: is this a problem with crashlytics or anything else?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same error sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868111/could-crashlytics-crash-on-android