# Could crashlytics crash on Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2, crashlytics

Here is an overview of a crash on fabric.io

- `java.lang.IllegalStateException` - Fatal exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread
- `rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException` - an exception originating somewhere in the depth of rx and ending in `SafeSubscriber#_onError`.
- `rx.exceptions.CompositeException` - 2 exceptions occured
- Casual chain - that's the interesting part

  ```
  Caused by rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.TrimmedThrowableData.<init>(TrimmedThrowableData.java:19)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.TrimmedThrowableData.<init>(TrimmedThrowableData.java:20)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.TrimmedThrowableData.<init>(TrimmedThrowableData.java:20)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsController.java:1090)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeFatal(CrashlyticsController.java:852)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$400(CrashlyticsController.java:59)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(CrashlyticsController.java:292)
     at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.call(CrashlyticsController.java:285)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
     at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
  ```
- `retrofit.RetrofitError` - 504 Gateway Timeout - probably supposed to be handled in one of the on `onError`

The version of Rx is `1.3.4`. At first I thought that Rx missed the actual exception that occurred in one of the `onError` methods, but I found this issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3679 
and it seems to be resolved, by looking at source code of `SafeSubscriber`
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/observers/SafeSubscriber.java
it seems like rx should report the exception from `onError` correctly.

So, there is a `CompositeException` containing a retrofit exception, which is supposed to happen from time to time, and a stacktrace with references to crashlytics code with no references to any app code. I wonder what I should make out of this.

Comment: First, are you up-to-date with Crashlytics? Maybe they're already fixed it?

Comment: There is nothing about it on changelog. Googling 'crashlytics crashed' or something like this doesn't give anything useful

Comment: Thanks! What version of the Crashlytics SDK are you using?

Comment: `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar`

Comment: We experience the same crash, we use ver. 2.6.0. I checked the changelog, there's no mention about any potential fix.

Comment: I am still not sure if that is `Crashlytics`'s fault. `Crashlytics` is probably just adding something to the composite exception, but the exception which actually causes the crash doesn't get reported, because it happens inside `onError`

Comment: @sasha199568 I am getting the same error, did you get any solution? Thanks